# SET GLOBAL lc_time_names=pt_BR

Tags: mysql, mariadb

> Access denied; you need (at least one of) the SUPER privilege(s) for this operation

When installing mysql, use the mysql_secure_installation security mode and delete some default options, including them (except for cheating), not allowing you to log in as root.

Now I need the super privileges to execute:

`SET GLOBAL lc_time_names=pt_BR`

How to proceed?

Answer (score 0):

```
SET SESSION lc_time_names = pt_BR;
```

But realize that it applies only to the rest of your 'session' (connection).

Or... Do you need to put it into `my.cnf` or your own `.my.cnf`?